# C++ 4*4 Array, moving down or right find largest sum

Tags: c++, arrays

So, I have to find largest sum in array of 4*4, that accepts number from 1-5, but only by moving down or right.
looks like this:

1 2 4 5

2 4 3 1

3 1 2 4

4 3 2 5

and output for this would be: right, right, right, down, down, down, 22

For now I have this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int orchard[4][4];
    int n;
    cout<<"Input numbers for orchard"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
            cin>>orchard[i][j];
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
            cout<<orchard[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your indentation is pretty bad, you know. And we're waiting for a question!

Comment: This is just code to print the grid, surely you could try to implement the other, more important logic?

Comment: @APerson: you're suggesting an exponential solution to a problem that has a simple linear solution? Not that its a big deal on 4x4 though.

Comment: An answer of the top of my head, though I am interested about this puzzle

Comment: @APerson One just has to iterate

Comment: Recursion implies repeated execution of a block of logic. It doesn't have to mean calling routines. The parameters are not repeated, so iteration is synonymous, no?

Answer (score 0):

A simple brute-force approach: All paths through the grid consist of exactly six moves, 3*right (R) and 3*down (D). So, create all possible permutations of RRRDDD, traverse the corresponding path and calculate the sum. Then simply search for the permutation(s)/path(s) with the largest sum.